# how uninstall/change windows phone 7.1 sdk?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I install windows phone 7.1 sdk. And then I  cant see phone app.in  VS10 (ultimate 64X)
I cant Uninstall/change windows phone 7.1 sdk.when I want to reinstall/uninstall/change occuring this error:

"A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup."

Comment: I came here wondering how to uninstall Windows Phone files in Windows 2012 server folder c:/program files (x86)/microsoft sdks/windows phone/ = 2.1GB which is alot. I found that it is due to: "Windows Phone 8.1 SDK is installed as part of VS 2013 Update 2. If you have update 2 , then you have to uninstall update 2 to remove phone SDK." as per post: Windows Phone 8.1 SDK on Windows 7 - Cannot update OR uninstall ; ; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/375f6569-1a75-4b7d-88fe-c23130853485/windows-phone-81-sdk-on-windows-7-cannot-update-or-uninstall?forum=wptools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled the "Hotfix for Windows Phone 7.1 Async CTP" in installed updates in control panel.

And I reinstalled the SDK again. This site do hint me for the correct solution : http://codexl.blogspot.com/2009/07/visual-studio-2008-setup-problem-has_29.html